# How do I pass a string with null bytes as an argument to a program while debugging in gdb

Tags: gdb, parameter-passing, buffer-overflow

I'm a cs student learning about buffer overflow attacks and I'm trying to write a very specific string to overflow a test program so I can jump to an arbitrary address. The problem is that the address I'm trying to jump contains null bytes which makes it very hard to input because I'm in gdb, I don't know how to (or  can't) do something like

```
python3 -c "print('\x90'*100 + 'address')" | ./test
```

or

```
./test < overflow.bin
```

While in gdb. I've tried things like

```
run $(python3 -c "print('\x90'*100 + 'address')")
run $(print'\x90\x90...\x90\x90address')
```

Unfortunately bash doesn't like null bytes and removes them from the input. How do I give the program a string in argv[1] that contains null bytes? Here's the program for context

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void function1(char * arg) {
    char buffer[100];
    strcpy(buffer, arg);
    printf("buffer is: '%s' \n", buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Welcome to this vulnerable program!\n");

    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("[error] one argument is required!\n");
    return -1;
    }

    printf("argv[0]: '%s' argv[1]: '%s'\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
    function1(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `run < overflow.bin`.  What does this do?

Comment: After trying run < overflow.bin it's says it needs an argument and exits at return -1, I've also tried run "A" < overflow.bin which correctly wrote A and only A to the buffer.

Comment: I should add the end goal of getting null bytes in the buffer is so that I can jump to an address like 0x0000ffffffffffdde0 that has null bytes. I assume that I need to somehow write those in a string that's passed to the program in argv[1]

Comment: I'm confused, do the two example commands that you gave or running `./test` work?  These should be passing data to `./test` via stdin, not the command line ... but the "needs an argument" message would indicate that test takes arguments on the command line ... so do your example commands even work?

Comment: Your right it doesn't work and i didn't test those until now cause I worked in gdb the whole time. The reason I wrote those commands is because that's how all the overflow tutorials do it so I atleast wanted to try the gdb equivalent of that. It works for them because they use gets.